# How to make my WEBP images from my website load in morzilla firefox is there a possible solution if yes then how?

Tags: javascript, web, webbrowser-control, e-commerce, web-deployment

WEBP is a image format which reduces the size of images and hence makes it possible for users to load website in less time and saves data but this format is not supported by morzilla firefox how to make this possible on morzilla firefox.

Comment: I'd really recommend only using WebP if you also provide a fallback image in a different format at this moment. Neither IE, Edge, Firefox or Safari currently support it. And it doesn't look like this will change soon...

Answer (score 0):

There's a ticket on [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=856375), based on that discussion, it's simply not supported.